# Trying to print a list in reverse?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print this list in descending order however this is not working any ideas why?

```
l = ["Germany",3,2,10,"Italy",7,9,1,"canada",4,5,3,"china",4,3,9]
d_list = []
for i in range(len(l)-2, -1, -3):
    d_list.append(l[i-1])
    d_list.append(l[i])
    d_list.append(l[i+1])
print (d_list)
```

Comment: have you tried the `reversed()` function?

Comment: I would prefer using a loop only

Comment: @stackoverflow I fixed your ident and you rollback the edit. In its current form, your code does not run

Comment: so it prints Italy 7,9,1 an then China 4,5,3 and so on

Comment: Because it has the highest Score(7)

Comment: but I already have a piece of code putting it into ascending I now need to do the oppisite

Comment: So you basically have a dict in list format, the data is associated, what about 9 etc..?

Comment: It's hard to understand what kind of ordering you have in mind. Please show your expected output.

Answer (score -1):

```
print [i for i in reversed(l)]
```

because reversed returns an iterator, so it wouldn't be enough to just print reversed.

Or what does descended order mean here for you?

Comment: The OP is not using reversed at all

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be to reverse the entire list, then print it.

```
l[::-1]
for x in range(len(l)):
    print(l[x-1])
```