# For Loop only printing of 1? Python

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to print a list in backwards order using a for loop, however my code only prints of a 1, any ideas why?

```
    sorted_list = ["jack",4,3,1,"jill",4,1,0,"bob",0,0,10,"tim",5,3,1,"sod",3,1,0]
    des_list = []
    for i in range(len(sorted_list)-2,-3,-1):
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i-2])
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i - 1])
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i])
        des_list.append(sorted_list[i+1])
    print(des_list)
```

Comment: Maybe try printing the whole list: `print(des_list)`, not just the element in index `i`

Comment: I'm no python programmer, but ain't that `print` outside the loop?

Comment: @Bathsheba I think he was trying to append all elements he wants to print to the list `dest_list` first, then print all its content.

Comment: Yep that's it I need to append all attributes first and then print the list

Comment: Please don't deface your question.

Comment: After @Christian mentioned that you needed to print out the whole list, instead of just the second element, that fixed the problem that you're asking ("why is my loop only printing out the value '1'?"). 

Since that isn't the problem you have anymore, I'd suggest rewriting your question to the real problem you're asking help for, like "How can I reverse chunks of data in a list?"

Comment: Additionally, this looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257795/trying-to-print-a-list-in-reverse?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to store the chunks of data into objects. That way, you can just call `reversed()` on the list of objects and handle the data that way.

If you want to keep the list in the format you have, you can loop through the list in "chunks", like this: `for i in range(0, len(sorted_list), 4):`.

So, for every 4 elements in the list, grab the chunk of of data using list slicing notation: `sorted_list[i:i+4]` and insert it to the front of the destination list.

Putting that together, you get this code:

```
sorted_list = ["jack",4,3,1,"jill",4,1,0,"bob",0,0,10,"tim",5,3,1,"sod",3,1,0]
des_list = []
for i in range(0, len(sorted_list), 4):
    des_list.insert(0, sorted_list[i:i+4])
print(des_list)
```

That will output this: `[['sod', 3, 1, 0], ['tim', 5, 3, 1], ['bob', 0, 0, 10], ['jill', 4, 1, 0], ['jack', 4, 3, 1]]`.

Keep in mind that that code will give you a list of lists, because `sorted_list[i:i+4]` returns a list, which is why it might be easier to use objects instead.

If you don't want to have a list of lists, you can reverse the sliced list, loop through each element in the reversed sliced list, and insert it one at a time to the destination list.

Doing that, you get this code:

```
sorted_list = ["jack",4,3,1,"jill",4,1,0,"bob",0,0,10,"tim",5,3,1,"sod",3,1,0]
des_list = []
for i in range(0, len(sorted_list), 4):
    for j in reversed(sorted_list[i:i+4]):
        des_list.insert(0, j)
print(des_list)
```

Which outputs this: `['sod', 3, 1, 0, 'tim', 5, 3, 1, 'bob', 0, 0, 10, 'jill', 4, 1, 0, 'jack', 4, 3, 1]`